# Jquery UI dialog text next to button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to put something like an auto-saving message next to the buttons at the bottom of the Jquery UI dialog. Is this possible? How do I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is light on details, but if you are looking to just add html to a button pane on the bottom of a jquery ui dialog box, try this:

```
  $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane").append("Auto-Saving");
```

Example here - http://jsbin.com/ejujat/edit#javascript,html